# Garbage Collection Not Running As Expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm having an issue where the overall memory usage of my .NET application continues to climb in our production environment. There is a small amount of up and down but it continues to trend up.

I thought it might be a memory leak in the code. However, we have another environment in AWS for user testing that rarely gets used. So I did a test on that environment where I tested the entire service with a large volume of requests under a short period of time. My test lasted about 20 minutes. I saw a corresponding spike in memory usage in the CloudWatch Dashboard. After that I let the test environment sit idle and after about two hours the memory usage dropped back down to the level it was at prior to starting my test.

Both environments are running the same version of the code. So if there really was a memory leak the test environment should have had the same issue. It seems like the only difference is that the test environment has much longer periods of being totally idle (no requests coming in).

Is there anything within AWS that could cause this to happen that I'm not aware of?

Comment: "Is there anything within AWS that could cause this to happen"  They don't own memory management, your application does.  Instrument your code to show where the memory is going.  I'm skeptical that your test leads to any particular conclusions.

Comment: @erik258 as I mentioned, the test environment has the same code as the prod environment. The testing done on the test environment was the same as what happens in prod environment. So same use case in both environments. Same code. One reclaims all memory. The other doesn't.

Comment: It looks like there actually might be something going on in AWS. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/configuring-net-garbage-collection-for-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/